# .NET perfomance test impact (NOT WEB)

Tags: .net, performance, testing, automated-tests

Are there any tools/techniques for continuous perfomance testing in .NET?
Ideally, I would like to find a tool, that can do with perfomance something like Test Impact does with corectness: remember the previous best result, fire-up a notification when I change the impacted code, then compare new test run with the previous one. I know that execution time may vary from run to run even on the same code, but I guess this issue can be solved with some test-repetition and confidence intervals. For example, if previous best execution time was t1 and new test execution time is t2, then:

test is green (passed) if t1*0.9 <= t2 <= t1*1.1

test is blue (improved) if t1*0.9 > t2

test is red (failed) if t1*1.1 < t2

I hope I explained my idea pretty well, so are there any similar tools? Yes, I tried to google it first, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

We do several things on my projects.  We use a tool like QFTest to record mouse and key movements then "run" the program to test the software.  We create bat files that execute a program (like a unit test) that does a "set up" that creates a starting point that then runs through all our business logic.  We save the results to a log file or database table for comparison. We also create stored procedures that test the DB side of the software by doing the same thing; mimic login, insert, fire rules, save off results.  We also do unit testing inside the IDE.  So in visual studio you set up all your unit tests (including set up and tear down) and run them, saving off your results to a file or database.

In short, unit testing is your friend and you have many ways of setting them up and recording your results.  [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/) is a great place to start as well as [test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)